# Sending IEnumerable to a view that already contains a model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the **view:**

```
@model tgpwebged.Models.sistema_DocType
 ...
```

this model is an entity used with textBoxFor and others html helpers

This is the **controller.**

```
public ActionResult AdminSettingAddTipo()
{
    IEnumerable<string> indices;

    using (tgpwebgedEntities context = new tgpwebgedEntities())
    {
        var obj = from u in context.sistema_Indexes select u.idName;
         indices = obj.ToList();
    }

    return PartialView(indices);
}
```

I have all I need here, I am using a model to create with the view so I am not allowed to send ´indices´ as a model because it´s not allowed to have 2 models in one view.

I don´t want to use ´Tupe´ now a parent view. I just want to know how is the best way to send my IEnumerable to the view.

I was thinking of ViewBag for the last option but I am avoiding ViewBag.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewBag is not a good choice. Create ViewModel using your list and your current Model:

```
    public class YourViewModel
    {

        public sistema_DocType Type { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> Indices {get;set;}
    }
```

Hope,it will help.

Comment: I always write my own constructor to class like this,and use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use ViewBag for whatever reason, you could create a Model specifically for the view that contains the info from the old model and the new indices you want.  This is a common pattern in MVC development.  You can even have the ViewModel be a Decorator for your current Model.

http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use strongly defined where you can, apply this to a model and send that model:

**Model**

```
public class MyModel{
     public List<sistema_Indexes> indecies {get;set;}

}
```

**Controller**

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();
model.indecies = context.sistema_Indexes.Select(u=> u.idName).ToList();
```